# Can this button submit post action two times?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a post action that get called twice, I looked through code and it looks like the problem is in UI and the way the form gets submitted. If someone can look at this input and tell me if this can somehow call post twice?

```
<input id="btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn pri continue-btn" 
value="@RecruiterResources.ContinueButton"
data-type="submit-with-progress" 
data-value="@Resources.Continue" 
data-progress="@Resources.Processing" />
```

On the button you see "Continue"(text) and when it clicked it changes on "Processing.."(text)

EDIT:
when i debug with F12 
I see 2 post actions

[image]

Comment: How is it you know the form is submitted twice?

Comment: Is it happening in IE, do you click the button from javascript ?

Comment: The post is sending an email and when i click I get 2 emails instead of 1.

Comment: @mybirthname  chrome, I just click on it

Comment: Use debug and check what is clicking the button twice.

Comment: When I've run into similar problems in the past, it has been an issue within my view or controller code as opposed to within the browser.

Comment: when i debug trough controller post method it jumps to the beginning of the post and then i can see how two call going trough the post method at the same time

Comment: Since `data-type`, `data-value`, and `data-progress` are not native to HTML, you must have something other than basic ASP.NET MVC running. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hit browser F12 button and record traffic; make sure there are actually two HTTP requests being sent.

Comment: @JohnWu I tryed and i see this => added a picture to the post

Comment: @JohnWu I have Google Tag Manager on the page. It can be that when i post and update the user and cookies it hits this GTM and some how trying to post again \

Comment: As Mike said, you have something else running on this page. Probably some JavaScript Wizard plugin or whatever. Debug your code and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, are you double-clicking the button?  Some Mac users tend to do that.

Just to be safe, you can add this code to disable the submit button after it is clicked the first time.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```